# Access javascript variable outside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, youtube-api

How can I get John, Liza, Peter, outside of the for loop?

```
var siblings = ["John", "Liza", "Peter"];

    for (var i=0; i < siblings.length; i++) {

      names = siblings[i];
      console.log(names) // correctly outputs John, Liza, Peter     
    }
console.log(names) // only gives Peter
```

**Update:** I was trying to reproduce the problem in a unit test case. But here is the whole thing.

So I made a request, and got an array

```
[ { kind: 'youtube#video',
    etag: '"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/XDKLx9FZygpwjYlzaTU-HAH31tw"',
    id: 'b4Bj7Zb-YD4',
    snippet:
     { publishedAt: '2016-10-28T07:00:01.000Z',
       channelId: 'UCaHNFIob5Ixv74f5on3lvIw',
       title: 'Calvin Harris - My Way (Official Video)',
       description: 'Calvin Harris - My Way (Official Video)\nDownload My Way:  http://smarturl.it/CHMyWay?IQid=yt\nListen to My Way: http://smarturl.it/StreamCH?IQid=yt\n\n---------\n\nFollow Calvin Harris:\nFacebook: https://www.facebook.com/calvinharris/ \nTwitter: https://twitter.com/CalvinHarris \nInstagram: https://www.instagram.com/calvinharris/ \nWebsite: http://calvinharris.com/ \n\n---------\n\nCalvin Harris - My Way (Lyrics)\n\nWhy wait \nTo say\nAt least I did it my way \nLie awake \nTwo faced \nBut in my heart I understand \nI made \nMy move \nAnd it was all about you \nNow I feel \nSo far removed \n\nYou were the one thing in my way \n\nMy way\nAway away away',
       thumbnails: [Object],
       channelTitle: 'CalvinHarrisVEVO',
       tags: [Object],
       categoryId: '10',
       liveBroadcastContent: 'none',
       localized: [Object] },
    statistics:
     { viewCount: '8313145',
       likeCount: '271119',
       dislikeCount: '7364',
       favoriteCount: '0' } },
  { kind: 'youtube#video',
    etag: '"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/c2pD6DG-ieqcYFEcGjGB31NYRKk"',
    id: '0zGcUoRlhmw',
    snippet:
     { publishedAt: '2016-10-24T14:00:01.000Z',
       channelId: 'UCRzzwLpLiUNIs6YOPe33eMg',
       title: 'The Chainsmokers - Closer ft. Halsey',
       description: 'Collage EP: \nPre-order on Amazon: http://smarturl.it/CollageAmz\nUrban Outfitters White Vinyl:  http://smarturl.it/CollageVinyl\n\n"Closer" ft. Halsey\niTunes: http://smarturl.it/CloseriT\nSpotify: http://smarturl.it/CloserStream\nApple Music: http://smarturl.it/CloserAM\nAmazon: http://smarturl.it/CloserAmz\n\nDirected by: Dano Cerny\n\nFollow The Chainsmokers:\nhttp://www.youtube.com/thechainsmokers\nhttp://www.twitter.com/thechainsmokers\nhttp://www.facebook.com/thechainsmokers\nhttp://www.instagram.com/thechainsmokers\nhttp://www.soundcloud.com/thechainsmokers\n\nFollow Halsey:\nTwitter: http://twitter.com/halsey\nFacebook: https://www.facebook.com/HalseyMusic\nInstagram: http://instagram.com/iamhalsey\nSpotify: http://smarturl.it/HalseySpotify\nNewsletter: http://www.iamhalsey.com/mailinglist\nPurchase Music: http://www.iamhalsey.com/badlandsbox',
       thumbnails: [Object],
       channelTitle: 'ChainsmokersVEVO',
       tags: [Object],
       categoryId: '10',
       liveBroadcastContent: 'none',
       localized: [Object] },
    statistics:
     { viewCount: '21315027',
       likeCount: '573642',
       dislikeCount: '19913',
       favoriteCount: '0',
       commentCount: '40899' } } 
]
```

So I put this in a variable e.g. siblings. And I loop through the entire array, to get snippet.title, snippet.publishedAt. Everything is good so far. But I want to push it into a new array, and make it available for use OUTSIDE of the loop.

My code as of now:

listVideos is the chunk I pasted before.

```
listVideos.forEach(function list(item) {
    data = new Array();
    title = item.snippet.title; 
    return data.push(title);

    });
console.log(data); // only gives first title. I want to get all titles in an array stored inside data. And make data available globally
```

setting the variable var data in the beginning does not work for me, because I have other functions outside of the forEach loop. Therefore, it has to be a flexible way which I can move anywhere I want, such as some kind of function scope.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to access outside of the for loop? you can access `siblings` values outside of the loop

Comment: why don't you just directly output the value of siblings it self as the original arrray I think what you want is to push each value inside new which makes no different to your original array

Answer (score 0):

It only says Peter because each loop iteration you're setting 'names' to that particular name. If you want to get ALL the names, then 'names' has to be an array and you should push the names in during the loop:

```
names.push(siblings[i])
```

Comment: there's no point to push to another array, you're going to get the same one as `siblings`

Comment: I know, but that seems to be what they're asking. Kind of hard to tell based on their wording

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = new Array();
names.push(siblings[i]);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need loop:

```
var siblings = ["John", "Liza", "Peter"];
var str = siblings.join(',');
console.log(str); //John,Liza,Peter
```